# Need of ApplicationContext object reference in a bean?

Tags: java, spring

What could be the possible usage of having a reference of applicationContext within a bean ?

Comment: If you wanted to dynamically grab bean instances, but did not want to tie yourself to annotations?

Comment: without obvious one, to get context from bean ? as for me, i don't see any case in which this could be usefull

Comment: If you wanted to do some Dependency Injection that was a little more complicated or required a little processing past simple cases of setting a Bean on a setter or calling a factory?

Comment: OH!  You were writing a framework with conditional DI, but was using a version of spring prior to supporting conditional DI through annotations!

Comment: @CodeChimp : So let's say there is a method getX() in a bean.The method checks : IF x==null then the bean is fetched using applicationContext. So in this case using an applicationContext to get the bean is a good idea rather than just autowiring bean ?

Comment: I would prefer autowiring myself where possible, and you don't need a setter method `setX()` to be able to autowire `X`.  But older versions of Spring didn't allow you to do things like conditional dependencies, like if you were writing a framework, and IF you have a particular service class available in your classpath, you wanted to do something different.  Concrete example: IF you see IMyService, then set `IMyService myService` to that instance.  Later, code could say `if (myService != null) { myService.doSomething(); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be useful to have a handle to an `ApplicationContext` or `ConfigurableApplicationContext` when writing infrastructure code. For example, if you wanted to write a service locator that should find all beans implementing an interface, you could

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void addFooServices() {

    for (... : this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(FooService.class)) {
        // do something with each
}
```

These kinds of uses are diminishing, since you can now (3.2, if not earlier) just inject

```
@Autowired
private List<FooService> fooServices;
```

But it can still be useful to have your hands on the container at times, e.g. to trigger a container refresh from JMX, or some other hackery.

Answer (score 0):

Will tell you one of our usage experience. We used the application context to get the collection of beans implementing a particular interface:

```
public class MyBean implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {



    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
        Collection<IMyInterface> implementors = context.getBeansOfType(IMyInterface.class).values();

    }
```

}

Comment: OP is asking WHY you would want to do this, not HOW.

Comment: @CodeChimp I read the question other way around. Updated my answer accordingly